# Can you update and add products by the same CSV file?

Tags: php, csv, prestashop, e-commerce, csv-import

I'm new to Prestashop, so my question may seem weird.

So I learned how to add products with CSV files and how to update them.

Just to check I update the products by Forcing ID Checks and User Reference as Primary Key.

Let's say I have an existing Database and CSV files containing new products and some old ones (Which I don't know their IDs in the database). How to add and update products by using the same CSV File? If I disable using reference key and forcing ID checks, I m going to have duplicates with different prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posted the same question in Prestashop forums, I have replied there [Prestashop forum link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1047255-can-you-update-and-add-products-by-the-same-csv-file/?tab=comments#comment-3324464),

Quoting for future readers:

`If you have access to the backend, which you must have in order to import a CSV simply go to Catalog->Products, get the product ids you need to import and use them in CSV product id column.`

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I will post my reply in the Prestashop forum.

Comment: You are welcome!
Maybe you could separate the imports from updates, like first creating a CSV without product_ids and import the products then another CSV with the product_ids from Catalog->Products and update what you need.

Comment: I know I might asking a lot here but could you help me with this issue ? 


I used CSV file to import new products. So in order to bulk import I uploaded my filed into a folder inside WWW folder named xxx and had the image URLs set to mydomain/xxx/imgTitle.jpg and still doesn't show and the image URL shows me a picture of an interrogation mark.

Please help me thanks

Comment: Did you set it with full URL (including https://) like ```https://example.com/xxx/imgTitle.jpg```?
And as a test, if you visit this URL, do you see that image?